# How to get NED velocity from GPS?

Tags: gps, velocity, kalman-filter

I have an Adafruit Ultimate GPS module which I am trying to fuse with a BNO055 IMU sensor. I'm trying to follow https://github.com/slobdell/kalman-filter-example this kalman-filtering example. Although most of his code is pretty clear, I looked at his input json file(https://github.com/slobdell/kalman-filter-example/blob/master/pos_final.json) and saw that he's getting velocity north, velocity east and velocity down from the GPS module. I looked at the NMEA messages and none seem to give me that. What am I missing? How to get these direction velocities?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*pos_final.json* is not the input file, but the output file. The input file is *taco_bell_data.json* and is found in the tar.gz archive. It contains the following variables:

```
"timestamp": 1.482995526836e+09,
"gps_lat": 0,
"gps_lon": 0,
"gps_alt": 0,
"pitch": 13.841609,
"yaw": 225.25635,
"roll": 0.6795258,
"rel_forward_acc": -0.014887575,
"rel_up_acc": -0.025188839,
"abs_north_acc": -0.0056906715,
"abs_east_acc": 0.00010974275,
"abs_up_acc": 0.0040153866
```

He measures position with a GPS and orientation/acceleration with an accelerometer. The NED velocities that are found in *pos_final.json* are estimated by the Kalman filter. That's one of the main tasks of a Kalman filter (and other observers): to estimate unknown quantities.

A GPS will often output velocities, but they will be relative to the body of the object. You can convert the body-relative velocties to NED-velocities if you know the orientation of the body (roll, pitch and yaw). Let's say you have a drone moving at heading 030°, and the GPS says the forward velocity is 1 m/s, the drone will have the following North velocity:

```
vel_north = 1 m/s * cos(30°) = 0.86 m/s
```

and the following East velocity:

```
vel_east = 1 m/s * sin(30°) = 0.5 m/s
```

This doesn't take into account roll and pitch. To take roll and pitch into account you can take a look at [rotation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) or [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) on Wikipedia.

The velocities are usually found in the [VTG telegram](http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/#vtg) the GPS outputs. It's not always being output. The GPS has to have that feature and it has to be enabled on the GPS. The RMC telegram can also be used.

The velocities from the GPS are often very noisy, which is why a Kalman filter is typically used instead of converting the body-relative velocities to NED-velocities with the method above. The GPS velocities will work fine in higher speeds though.

Comment: Are you sure pos_final is the output file? Because if you look at his code, he's reading that file and inputting those values into the Kalman filter. But thanks for the rest of the explanation, seems to clear up some things!

Comment: @ShantanuMhapankar You are right, I jumped to conclusions. I read the readme, but the code has changed since then (without the readme being updated). In the original code it's pretty much like I wrote. The author later added velocities from the GPS, according to [this](http://scottlobdell.me/2017/03/reading-velocity-gps-emlid-navio2-hardware-ublox-gps/) post. I can't understand the Doppler shift code though, so I can't comment on that. The velocities are usually estimated by the Kalman filter.